# Cannot move app to SD card: "Not enough storage space"

Tags: sd-card, installation, app2sd

**Disclaimer: There are many similar questions, but: 1) No answer there helped me, 2) This one provides additional info and questions, 3) Others seem to be related to Android versions < 8, so the scheme looks different. So it wouldn't really help adding a bounty.**

I am using Android 8. As far as I could find, I cannot install apps directly to SD card. I have to install them regularly, and then move them via *Settings* -> *Apps* -> *Workplace (App info)* -> *Storage*.
I mean to move Facebook Workplace to the SD card, and I keep getting "Not enough storage space".
I have plenty of space there (more than 6Gb).
The app shows as taking up 138Mb. I have 530Mb available in the internal memory.

What I tried:

1. Moving other apps to the SD card. It worked.
2. Removing and reinstalling Facebook Workplace. Moving to SD card. It failed the same.
3. Ejecting the SD card and inserting it again. I had to rebuild my home screen, but still cannot move the app.

What I did not try:

1. Formatting the SD card. I guess it is too much work to try, and many others reported it does not work.
2. Reinstalling the OS. It is a corporate device.
3. Rooting the phone. Ibid.
4. A custom ROM. Ibid.
5. Using an app. It seemed to me that this was required for older Android versions. Now Android has that capability builtin.

Other similar questions are:

[Unable to move few Apps to SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27816/unable-to-move-few-apps-to-sd-card) .
[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27822/81584) provides reasons why an app might not support moving to SD, but I guess Android 8 is already aware of this, and shows the option only if possible.
Plus, I wouldn't know how to tell if Facebook Workplace is one such app.

And none of this has an answer that helps me (many of these are very old questions):

[Getting "not enough space" error even i have enough space in sd card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162360/getting-not-enough-space-error-even-i-have-enough-space-in-sd-card)

["Cannot Move App Not Enough Storage Space" Error Message](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157650/cannot-move-app-not-enough-storage-space-error-message)

[Cannot move app to sd-card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55438/cannot-move-app-to-sd-card)

[Storage space in SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/184489/storage-space-in-sd-card)

[Getting "not enough space" error even i have enough space in sd card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162360/getting-not-enough-space-error-even-i-have-enough-space-in-sd-card)

[why do I keep getting message saying unable to move app not enough storage space ?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/189262/why-do-i-keep-getting-message-saying-unable-to-move-app-not-enough-storage-space)

[Move app to SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43672/move-app-to-sd-card)

[Move apps to SD card in Marshmallow without using internal SD Card storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144906/move-apps-to-sd-card-in-marshmallow-without-using-internal-sd-card-storage)

[My apps don't move to SD-card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154918/my-apps-dont-move-to-sd-card)

[Move apps to internal SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84657/move-apps-to-internal-sd-card)

["Couldn't move app. Not enough storage space." I have factory reset my phone, inserted & formated a new 64GB MicroSD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77649/couldnt-move-app-not-enough-storage-space-i-have-factory-reset-my-phone-in)

[Why do I keep getting "not enough storage space"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135307/why-do-i-keep-getting-not-enough-storage-space)

More old questions:

[App can't be moved to SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25439/app-cant-be-moved-to-sd-card)

[What does the 'Failed to move application. Not enough memory' error mean when choosing 'Move to SD card'?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3437/what-does-the-failed-to-move-application-not-enough-memory-error-mean-when-ch)

["Couldn't move app. Not enough storage space." I have factory reset my phone, inserted & formated a new 64GB MicroSD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77649/couldnt-move-app-not-enough-storage-space-i-have-factory-reset-my-phone-in)